# Expresso Store and PayPal TLS 1.2 Upgrade

Tags: expresso-store, paypal

I have a site running EE 2.8.1 with Expresso Store 2.3.1. The recent TLS 1.2 PayPal upgrade has caused PayPal Express payments to fail - giving the error - *Sorry, there was an unexpected error communicating with the payment gateway.*

Is this being caused by the Store code? I need to determine if the issue is software or server related. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of the time, this is a server issue. Your host will need to upgrade your server to support later versions of PHP/cURL/etc that allow TLS 1.2.

In general I'd also recommend upgrading Expresso Store to the latest version for EE2 but it shouldn't technically be necessary for this issue to be fixed.